# group array into subarrays by part of key in php

Tags: php, arrays, grouping, sub-array

I have array from post like this:

```
$post = array (
  'cib_1_34b2e5386658' => 'value1',
  'cib_2_34b2e5386658' => 'value2',
  'cib_3_34b2e5386658' => 'value3',
  'cib_4_34b2e5386658' => 'value4',
  'cib_5_34b2e5386658' => 'value5',
  'cib_6_ec98ea5bee36' => 'value6',
  'cib_7_ec98ea5bee36' => 'value7',
  'cib_8_ec98ea5bee36' => 'value8',
  'cib_9_ec98ea5bee36' => 'value9',
);
```

What i need is group it in subarrays by id part of key like this:

```
$values = array(
    '34b2e5386658' => array(
        'cib_1' => 'value1',
        'cib_2' => 'value2',
        'cib_3' => 'value3',
        'cib_4' => 'value4',
        'cib_5' => 'value5',
    ),
    'ec98ea5bee36' => array(
        'cib_6' => 'value6',
        'cib_7' => 'value7',
        'cib_8' => 'value8',
        'cib_9' => 'value9'
    )
);
```

I can do this with foreach loops, but I would like to use some array functions to make it cleaner and shorter.

Comment: Show the loop method, it's probably the shortest and cleanest.

Comment: Just curious, why not have form inputs like `name="values[34b2e5386658][cib_1]"` this will get you that result.

Comment: Ah, You are right. The form is dynamically generated and probably i need to rewrite the generating code to have it like You said. Thanks.